# C# WinForms, accessing array of a class on click without creating a new instance of the class

Tags: c#, class, optimization, onclick

I've got the following (parts of) classes:

**Tile class:**
*Names of variables and such are translated*

```
class Tile
{
    public PictureBox[] directNeighbors= new PictureBox[8]; 

    public PictureBox[] farNeighbors = new PictureBox[16]; 

    PictureBox tilePB = new PictureBox();
    public PictureBox GetTilePB{ get
        {
            return vakjePB;
        }
    }

    public PictureBox InitializeVakje(PictureBox tilePB, int vakWidth, int vakHeight, int iMapWidth, int iMapHeight)
    {
        tilePB.Name = "vak";
        tilePB.Size = new Size(vakWidth, vakHeight);
        tilkePB.Location = new Point((tileWidth+ 1) * iMapWidth, (tileHeight+ 1) * iMapHeight); //tileWidth and tileHeight are already generated integers.
        tikePB.BackColor = Color.Gray;


        return tilePB;
    }
}
```

**Field class:**    *Names of variables and such are translated*

```
class Field
{
    public static readonly int mapWidth = 7;
    public static readonly int mapHeight = 7;

    private Tile[,] fieldTiles = new Tile[mapWidth, mapHeight];

    private PictureBox[,] _field = new PictureBox[mapWidth, mapHeight]; 
    public GetField
    {
        get
        {
            return _Field;
        }
    }

    public void InitializePlayfield(int vakWidth, int vakHeight, VirusUI mainUI) 
    {
        for (int iMapPictureBoxY = 0; iMapPictureBoxY < mapHeight; iMapPictureBoxY++)
        {
            for (int iMapPictureBoxX = 0; iMapPictureBoxX < mapWidth; iMapPictureBoxX++)
            {
                Tile tile = new Tile(); //Maak een nieuwe instantie van klasse 
                fieldTiles[iMapPictureBoxX, iMapPictureBoxY] = vak;
                _field[iMapPictureBoxX, iMapPictureBoxY] = tile.InitializeTile(vak.GetTilePB, vakWidth, vakHeight, iMapPictureBoxX, iMapPictureBoxY);
                mainUI.Controls.Add(_field[iMapWidth, iMapHeight]);

                _field[iMapPictureBoxX, iMapPictureBoxY].Click += ColorNeighbors;

            }
        }
    }

    public void ColorNeighbors(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox tilePB = (PictureBox)sender;

        var tile = new Tile();

        for(int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++)
            {
                if(GetField[x, y] == tilePB)
                {
                    tilePB = fieldTiles[x, y];
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < tile.directNeighbors.Length; i++)
        {
            if(tile.directNeighbors[i] != null)
            {
                tile.directNeighbors[i].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < tile.farNeighbors.Length; i++)
        {
            if(tile.farNeighbors[i] != null)
            {
                tile.farNeighbors[i].BackColor = Color.Orange;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Context:**
Currently, the `_field[,]` has 49 Tiles with an onclick event set to `ColorNeighbors`. All (direct and far) neighbors of a certain get collored when you click on that tile.

Each Tile consists out of a PictureBox that gets drawn and handles the onclick event. In order to get the Tile's neighbors I have to check which PictureBoxis clicked, compare the sender with each PictureBox in `_field[,]` is clicked and then setting "vakje" (New Tile) to the Tile at the same position in `fieldTiles` as the sender is in `_field`.

Alyhough this works, I've got multiple "issues" with it:

1. I have to create a new tile each time I click on a PictureBox, otherwise the `tile.directNeighbors[i]...` gives an error since "tile" doesn't exist in the current context.
2. I just find the code ugly...

**Question:**
Is there a way to access `directNeighbors[]` in Tile without constantly creating a new Tile for it, while still "knowing" what tile is clicked? Or does `var tile = new Tile();` already do the job?

Comment: What is the actual problem of creating a new Tile each time you click on a picture box? It sounds a bit like [micro optimization theatre](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/) to me. With regard to whether your code is ugly or not and how it could be (re-)written in a more concise and elegant manner, i think this would be more fitting for https://codereview.stackexchange.com.